# How to update maps in a document in firestore with a list of items

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, logic

[image]

I have a list [a,d,f]. I want to increment those fields in the test map respectively.

If I were to hard code it, it'll look something like this.

```
firestore.collection('x').doc('y').update({
        'test.a':FieldValue.increment(1),
        'test.d':FieldValue.increment(1),
        'test.f':FieldValue.increment(1),
      });
```

But what if the list always changes. How can increment the map according to the list every time? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a map from that list:

```dart
var myList = ["a", "d"];
var myMap = { for (var item in myList) 'test.$item': FieldValue.increment(1) };
print(myMap);
// {test.a: FieldValue.increment(1), test.d: FieldValue.increment(1)}

firestore.collection('x').doc('y').update(myMap)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. It worked. Do you happen to also know how to do this exact same thing on typescript??

Comment: I'm working on firebase cloud functions and would love to put this as a function but it would require typescript.

Comment: @scottlee yes, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzchsx38). The logic remains same. Just loop over they array and add the properties in a map.

Comment: Hmm, but it seems to come with the ' '. Is there a way to do without the apostrophe in the increment??

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `' '`. Can you share a screenshot of what you are referring to? I do have a comment there. Replace `"increment"` with `FieldValue.increment(1)`

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question above to add in the screenshot.

Comment: @scottlee yes, remove the `" "` from that `forEach`. It should be `list.forEach((item) => myMap[item] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1))`. I had those quotes in JSFiddle else it would have thrown an error that admin is not defined.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you very much! Thanks for taking the time to share with me :) Appreciate it!